# What will decode "email%2540yahoo.com" value in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

My variable with javascript looks like this:

```
var email = encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'email\']').val())
```

`email` is clearly being encoded and is producing this when sent to server: `email%2540yahoo.com`

What function in PHP will decode this value properly?

I've tried using `html_entity_decode`

Comment: [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) (x2)

Comment: The email is being urlencoded twice

Answer (score 5):

The correct url encoding for @ is %40.

When a url, for example from an e-mail, with the encoded @ character in it, is redirected using a rewrite rule, it will be rewritten as %2540 (the % is encoded as %25). If you keep rewriting / redirecting, you will replace % with %25 each time, ending up with %25252540 (or more 25, you get the picture).

For example clicking this:

```
http://example.org?email=info%40example.org
```

Will produce after a rewrite and redirect using a rewrite rule:

```
https://example.org?info%2540example.org
```

in the browser address bar, which does not correctly translate to info@example.org in php.

Answer (score 4):

> What function in PHP will decode this value properly?

You don't need to decode anything. `$_GET["email"]` and `$_POST["email"]` will work just fine. The `encodeURIComponent` function is used to properly url encode a url to avoid having invalid urls. If you have a valid url, PHP will successfully be able to read the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo urldecode(urldecode('email%2540yahoo.com')); // email@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `urldecode(<value_to_decode_here>);`